# change the image background every second

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, uiimageview, transition

I have two images: "back1" and "back2" what I want is to put "back1" at the background and then after 2 seconds change it to "back2" with fade effect, and then change "back2" to "back1" with fade effect again and again every two seconds. How can I do that please ? I think that I must use CATransition or something like that . sorry for my english I'm french:/

Answer (score 5):

Using a `static` variable helps with the looping:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    myImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bck2.png",@"bck3.jpg",@"bck1.jpg",nil];

    updateBCK = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(3600.0) target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    [updateBCK fire];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

After adding the above code to the `viewdidload` define the action:

```
-(void)changeImage{

    //background.alpha=0.5;
    static int i=0;

    if (i == [myImages count]){
        i=0;
    }

    [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    background.alpha=1;
    background.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]];
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
    i++;

}
```

Comment: Same action , I wanna do it on UIButton Image. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

U can achieve this using NSTimer. Call a method through NSTimer which sets the BG image of ur app at regular intervals. Hope this helps.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
UIView *mainView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
mainView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.view=mainView;
[mainView release];
randomView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 100, 100)];
randomView.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
[mainView addSubview:randomView];
[randomView release];
myImages=[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"arrow.jpeg",@"default.jpeg",@"user.jpeg",@"home.jpeg", nil]retain];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(2.0) target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
NSLog(@"%@",myImages);
```

Add the above code in the viewDidLoad method.

```
-(void)changeImage{
randomView.alpha=0.5;
if(i>3){
   i=0;
    [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    randomView.alpha=1;
    randomView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]];
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
    i+=1;}
else{
    [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    randomView.alpha=1;
    randomView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]];
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
    i+=1;}
```

Add the above code in a user defined method called  -(void)changeImage

Comment: and what about the fade effect

Comment: for the fade effect vary the alpha of the image within the animation interval and u will achieve the effect u need.

Comment: but how can I set the background every time what is the code for this , because I want a random image between ten to be set

Comment: i will come up with a solution with code ...if u could wait for sometime please

Comment: @bernard langue....chk out the code i have posted in the answer...Hope that helps

Comment: no it doesn't work, the image turn to black without fade out effect and then another image appears with fade in effect.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 4 and above you could using Animation Block - this is very fast and gives a cleaner interface.
See [UIView - animateWithDuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)